# Laravel - Impersonation redirect issue

Tags: laravel, admin

I currently have an admin panel that allows admins to login via other users accounts and view their accounts as the user would which redirects to a subdomain.

so ill be on the url `http://example.local/admin/users` which is a list of the users then when you log in as a particular user via this route.

**Login as user**

```
    Route::get('/users/{id}/login_as', function ($id) {

    $user = App\User::withTrashed()->find($id);

    $user->changelogs()->create([
        'action' => 'Admin logged in as user'
    ]);

    session()->put(['og_user' => auth::user()]);

    \Auth::logout();
    \Auth::loginUsingId($id);

    return redirect('/dashboard');
});
```

This will then redirect to the users page on how they see the platform but this will change to a sub domain `http://subdomain.example.local/......`.

I currently have a header that appears once logged in that contains a `return to admin` button which then logs you out of that user and returns you back to the admin page you was originally on.

**Return to admin button**

```
@if(session()->has('og_user') && auth::user())
    <div class="signed_in">
        <div class="container inner">
            <h5 class="text-light mb-0">
                Logged-in as {{ auth::user()->name }}
            </h5>

            <a href="/admin/{{session()->get('og_user')['id']}}/log_in_as" class="btn btn-secondary ml-auto">
                Return to admin
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

**Login as admin**

```
    Route::get('/admin/{id}/log_in_as', function ($id) {

    session()->forget('og_user');

    \Auth::logout();
    \Auth::loginUsingId($id);

    return back();
});
```

the problem i am having is once im logged in under another user on a subdomain and then i return to admin it directs me back to the admin page but under the sub domain still `http://subdomain.example.local/dashboard` with that domains UI theme when i want it to go back to `example.local/dashboard`

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: A easier way for impersonation in laravel is this package: https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate I use this and the implementation takes 5 minutes

Comment: The functionality is already in place for this throughout the app, can i avoid using this package?

Comment: it does log out because when i dump ` \Auth::loginUsingId($id);` it returns the admin's id i was originally logged in and directs to the correct page it just stays on the wrong users domain

Comment: your return back anchor has '/admin...'  What i think is happening is that it is just adding admin at the end of whatever url you have on the browser. `url` helper will do the same. I suggest using named route.

Comment: yeah you are correct its just adding `admin/dashboard` but ignoring the subdomain url

Comment: Do you mind providing an example?

Answer (score 0):

You use

```php
return back();
```

This function will return you to the `previous` page: in your case, the previous page is in the `subdomain`. So you don't want to go back.

Use a direct link to the page you want to visit instead:

```php
return redirect('your desired route');
```

Comment: so if i do return back() it then directs to this page `.example.local/dashboard` can you not just remove the `.` ? also for the return redirect what if your on a sub domain and want to redirect to a sub domain that maybe different and not the same? e.g on `testdomain.example.com` then redirect to `domain.example.com` the idea is to have different accounts that have there own subdomains to the platform so whenever you click return to admin it always returns you back to the admin page you are logged in with the correct UI etc

Comment: Just `return redirect('http://my.admin.domain.com/my-admin-dashboard')`